# Xamarin.Forms UI not responding

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms app using the Prism library.  The app has a phone component to it with integration to CallKit and a SIP library.  When the device is locked, a call can be received, which results in the native phone UI for iOS.  User can answer the call and hangup.  Within the app, there is a Xamarin.Forms page to handle calls.  There are events from the iOS service that deals with the calls to interact with the "shared project".  The issue that I am running in to is that when the user unlocks the device and returns to the app, the UI is non-responsive.

Scenario:

1. User starts app and logs in.
2. User locks device
3. Incoming call received
4. User answers call
5. Behind the scenes (i.e. native phone UI), the call service communicates with the "shared project" to display a Call Screen in the app.  Since the phone is locked, the user will not see this now.
6. User hangs up.
7. When user hangs up, the call service communicates with the "shared project" that the call has been terminated and to return to the previous screen.
8. User then unlocks the screen
9. App is on same screen as when user locked device, but UI is not responsive.

To navigate to the call page, I am doing:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(targetPage, null, useModalNavigation: null, animated: animated);
```

and to return to previous page:

```
await NavigationService.GoBackAsync(animated: false, parameters: parameters);
```

NavigationService is of type INavigationService from Prism.

The essential question is: what would make the navigation appear to work, but result in a non-responsive UI?  I've found in the past that I need to do the navigation on the main thread.  Is there anything else I need to look for?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood that you are looking for a method just like the OnAppearing method of forms page.
You need to `implement interface` `INavigatedAware` to your ViewModel. By doing this, 2 methods will be added to your `ViewModel` `"NavigatedTo"` and `"NavigatedFrom"`. You need to put your logic into the `"NavigatedTo"` method. This method will be triggered whenever that particular page will appear on the screen.